# Opening/Manipulating/Saving TextFile in Delphi

Tags: delphi, text-files

I am a Delphi Noob and I have searched and stepped through my code and not understanding why this outputs a textfile without contents. It is supposed to open a textfile in dialog box which works, it assigns the chosen file `origFile`, then I want to assign that file to another named `myFile` so I can manipulate without altering the actual original file, then I want to save `myFile` as `(sOrigFileName + 'B.BACKWARDS.TXT')` which it does but it skips over the `while not Eof(origFile) do` and goes to `CloseFile`. I am posting my code below.

The requirements are to use a `TextFile` vs `TStringList` otherwise I would and have done this with `TStringList`. Also another issue is it is stating that `myFile` is not found, I thought `assignFile(myFile, sOrigFileName);` was creating `myFile`....

```
procedure TForm1.btnOpenFileCClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    origFile, myFile : TextFile;
    OpenDialog1 : TOpenDialog;
    sOrigFileName, sNewFileName, sLine, sNewLine : String;

begin
    //Selects txt File of the users choosing
    OpenDialog1 := TOpenDialog.Create(self);
    OpenDialog1.Filter := '*.txt';

    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      //AssignFile(origFile, OpenDialog1.FileName);
      sOrigFileName := OpenDialog1.FileName;
      AssignFile(origFile, sOrigFileName);
    end;

    //BACKWARDS
    sNewFileName := sOrigFileName + '.B.BACKWARDS.TXT';
    DeleteFile(sNewFileName);  //Delete old File if exists
    AssignFile(myFile, sNewFileName);

    Reset(origFile);

    while not Eof(origFile) do
    begin
       Rewrite(myFile);
       Readln(origFile, sLine); //takes line into a string Var
       sNewLine := AnsiReverseString(sLine); //reverses and places to  new Var
       WriteLn(myFile,sNewLine);
    end;

    //Clean up
    CloseFile(OrigFile);
    CloseFile(myFile);
```

Comment: Chiastic-Security mentioned to move the ReWrite under the Reset(OrigFile) which fixed myFile not found issue. Still getting a blank text file at the end vs. a text file that contents have been reversed

Comment: Why are you using the old Pascal style? Use TStringList, as Remy demonstrates. That is easiest, unless your file is extremely large (TStringList will load it into memory entirely and in the process, it will need some extra memory as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me as though you need the `Rewrite(myFile)` to be outside the loop, straight after the `Reset(origFile)`.

Comment: This did correct my file not found issue, however I still get a blank text document vs. the original File that has reversed text. It skips over the Eof(origFile) statement

Comment: If `OpenDialog1.Execute()` returns False, you should be exiting your procedure instead of proceeding to access a file that is never opened. You are also creating a new `TOpenDialog` every time and never freeing it until app exit, so you are wasting memory. Either reuse the same `TOpenDialog` object each time, or free it each time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not sure by what you mean I am creating a new TOpenDialog everytime. Later on in the code I do free it up. But I only see one TOpenDialog when the user clicks the btn. If I am missing what your intending to point out please show me what you mean I would like to know. Also just FYI the original Text file was blank, someone erased its contents accidentally (maybe even myself) and that is why it was returning a blank text file at the end.

Comment: @DelphiNoob: every time `btnOpenFileCClick()` is called, it performs `TOpenDialog.Create()`, which creates a new instance of the dialog component.  The `btnOpenFileCClick()` code you showed does not call `OpenDialog1.Free()`. If it actually does call `Free()` in your project, you omitted that portion. But you don't have a `try/finally` block protecting it, and there are areas of code you did show that could raise an exception, thus bypassing the `Free()` if a file I/O error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.btnOpenFileCClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  origFile, myFile : TextFile;
  OpenDialog1 : TOpenDialog;
  sOrigFileName, sNewFileName, sLine, sNewLine : String;
begin
  OpenDialog1 := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    OpenDialog1.Filter := '*.txt';
    if not OpenDialog1.Execute then
      Exit;
    sOrigFileName := OpenDialog1.FileName;
  finally
    OpenDialog1.Free;
  end;

  sNewFileName := sOrigFileName + '.B.BACKWARDS.TXT';
  DeleteFile(sNewFileName);

  AssignFile(origFile, sOrigFileName);
  try
    Reset(origFile);

    AssignFile(myFile, sNewFileName);
    try
      Rewrite(myFile);

      while not Eof(origFile) do
      begin
        Readln(origFile, sLine);
        sNewLine := AnsiReverseString(sLine);
        WriteLn(myFile, sNewLine);
      end;
    finally
      CloseFile(myFile);
    end;
  finally
    CloseFile(OrigFile);
  end;
end;
```

I don't know why you are required to use `TextFile`, that is a very old school approach and not modern at all.  You should use `TStreamReader/Writer` if you have access to them:

```
procedure TForm1.btnOpenFileCClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  origFile: TStreamReader;
  myFile : TStreamWriter;
  OpenDialog1 : TOpenDialog;
  sOrigFileName, sNewFileName, sLine, sNewLine : String;
begin
  OpenDialog1 := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    OpenDialog1.Filter := '*.txt';
    if not OpenDialog1.Execute then
      Exit;
    sOrigFileName := OpenDialog1.FileName;
  finally
    OpenDialog1.Free;
  end;

  sNewFileName := sOrigFileName + '.B.BACKWARDS.TXT';
  DeleteFile(sNewFileName);

  origFile := TStreamReader.Create(sOrigFileName);
  try
    myFile := TStreamWriter.Create(sNewFileName, False, origFile.CurrentEncoding);
    try
      while not origFile.EndOfStream do
      begin
        sLine := origFile.ReadLine;
        sNewLine := AnsiReverseString(sLine);
        myFile.WriteLine(sNewLine);
      end;
    finally
      myFile.Free;
    end;
  finally
    OrigFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise, use `TStringList` instead:

```
procedure TForm1.btnOpenFileCClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  myFile : TStringList;
  OpenDialog1 : TOpenDialog;
  sOrigFileName, sNewFileName, sLine, sNewLine : String;
  I: Integer;
begin
  OpenDialog1 := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    OpenDialog1.Filter := '*.txt';
    if not OpenDialog1.Execute then
      Exit;
    sOrigFileName := OpenDialog1.FileName;
  finally
    OpenDialog1.Free;
  end;

  sNewFileName := sOrigFileName + '.B.BACKWARDS.TXT';
  DeleteFile(sNewFileName);

  myFile := TStringList.Create;
  try
    myFile.LoadFromFile(sOrigFileName);

    for I := 0 to myFile.Count-1 do
    begin
      sLine := myFile[I];
      sNewLine := AnsiReverseString(sLine);
      myFile[I] := sNewLine;
    end;

    myFile.SaveToFile(sNewFileName);
  finally
    myFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I would use the TStringList approach. That is by far the most convenient way to to manipulate the text.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Convenient, but not efficient for large files, especially in D2009+ because it wastes a LOT of memory (up to 3x the file size!) before it even begins to parse the file data. For D2009+, I would lean more towards `TStreamReader`/`TStreamWriter` instead because of their lower memory footprint.

Comment: no, not for large files. I know about the overhead. But extremely convenient for not-so-large files.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I have used the TStringList approach successfully, Thank you, these are training apps I need to write for the company I am working for. We have some oldschool apps still out there and this I assume is why we are required to do the same thing using different objects.